# Using Google Analytics offline

Tags: google-analytics

Is there any way I can use Google Analytics offline (i.e., without Internet)? I know that there are some exports for statistics which I have chosen but is there anything that can help me download almost all (or at least the important things) and which can I use for browsing stats offline?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up weekly/daily email reports for the reports you wish to see offline. Those will then be available in your inbox; if the inbox is available offline then the reports should be too.